# Dfa accepting all strings with odd number of 0's and odd number of 1's

Tags: automata

The alphabets are Σ={0,1}

Want to design a **DFA** that accept all strings with *odd number* of *0's* and *odd number* of *1's* is it possible?

Comment: Of course. You can write a DFA that accepts the strings with odd number of zeros, you can write a DFA that accepts the strings with odd number of ones, thus you should be able to write a DFA that accepts the strings with odd number of zeros and odd number of ones via the general construction for the DFA of $L_1\cap L_2$.

Comment: Kindly tell me how, can you design?

Comment: No, I am incapable of drawing on this site.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: There's one with four states which is not hard to write down explicitly, where each state is labelled (even, even), (even, odd), (odd, even), and (odd, odd). Is this a hint enough?